# duplicated rows in RDD

Tags: caching, apache-spark, persist, rdd

I encountered the following problem in spark:

```
...
while(...){
    key = filtersIterator.next()
    pricesOverLeadTimesKeyFiltered = pricesOverLeadTimesFilteredMap_cached
       .filter(x => x._1.equals(key))
       .values
    resultSRB = processLinearBreakevens(pricesOverLeadTimesKeyFiltered)
    resultsSRB = resultsSRB.union(resultSRB)
}
....
```

By this way, I accumulate the same resultSRB in resultsSRB.
But here are "some" tricks allowing me to add a different/right resultSRB for each iteration

- call `resultSRB.collect()` or `resultSRB.foreach(println)` or `println(resultSRB.count)` after each `processLinearBreakevens(..)` call
- perform the same operation on `pricesOverLeadTimesKeyFiltered` at the beginning of `processLinearBreakevens(..)`

It seems I need to ensure that all operations must be "flushed" before performing the union. I already tried the union through a temporary variable, or to persist resultSRB, or to persist `pricesOverLeadTimesKeyFiltered` but still the same problem.

Could you help me please?
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my assumption is correct; that all of these are `var`, then the problem is closures. `key` needs to be a `val` as it is being lazily captured into your `filter`. So, when it is finally acted on, the filtering is always using the last state of `key`

My example:

```
def process(filtered : RDD[Int]) = filtered.map(x=> x+1)

var i = 1
var key  = 1
var filtered = sc.parallelize(List[Int]())
var result = sc.parallelize(List[Int]())
var results = sc.parallelize(List[Int]())
val cached = sc.parallelize(1 to 1000).map(x=>(x, x)).persist
while(i <= 3){
    key = i * 10
    val filtered = cached
       .filter(x => x._1.equals(key))
       .values
    val result = process(filtered)
    results = results.union(result)
    i = i + 1
}
results.collect
//expect 11,21,31 but get 31, 31, 31
```

To fix it, change `key` to be `val` in the `while` loop and will get your expected `11,21,31`